# Dudas sobre metodo EDIT, UPDATE y rutas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con el auth por defecto de laravel, la pregunta que tengo es que para editar el perfil ¿es necesario pasar el $id del usuario en el formulario edit? este $id es capturado por el metodo EDIT del controlador UserController y luego por el metodo UPDATE, ¿se puede solo ocupar auth() desde el formulario al controlador?, ¿hay alguna forma de hacer mas limpias las urls?

Soy nuevo en laravel y tengo que hacer una pequeña aplicación que luego tendrá una api de

Les adjunto screenshot de las rutas de perfil de usuario, form y controlador

Rutas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador metodo Edit
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador metodo Update
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las url son limpias, lo que vos estás queriendo hacer es no pasar `id` para editar o actualizar y eso tiene lógica ya que eso solo lo podría hacer el usuario autenticado.

Lo que tenés que hacer es:

// Ruta

```
Route::get('panel/profile', 'UserController@edit');
Route::put('panel/profile', 'UserController@update');
```

// Controlador

```
public function edit() {
  $user = auth()->user(); // si el usuario esta autenticado te devuelve el User
  ...
}

public function update(Request $request)
  $user = auth()->user();
  ...
}
```

Te recomiendo incorporar el middleware `auth` al constructor de tu controlador

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me dejas la película muy clara. La pregunta que me sale es ¿entonces en el form de editar no le paso el $id del usuario?, como sería eso entonces?

Comment: no, no es necesario. Se sabe que el usuario será el que esté logueado.

Answer (score 1):

***¿Es necesario pasar el $id del usuario en el formulario edit?***

Supongo que te refieres al formulario para hacer update, en ese caso, sí, sí lo es, de otra forma no sabrías que usuario vas a actualizar, ah no ser que siempre llames por defecto al usuario logeado mediante `Auth`.

---

***¿Se puede solo usar auth() desde el formulario al controlador?***

Sí, puedes llamar al usuario logeado usando `Auth::user()->id`.

---

***¿Hay alguna forma de hacer mas limpias las urls?***

Laravel usa rutas amigables, ya son lo más limpias posibles a mi parecer, a no ser tu concepción de 'limpias' sea otra.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me ha servido mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Sí hay una manera de hacer más limpias tus **url**.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
Route::resource('nombredelaruta','NombreControlador')
```

Con esta sola línea si te vas a la consola y ejecutas `php artisan route:list`,
verás las 4 url básicas como son **Get, Post,  Put y Delete.**

Comment: Hola conozco los recursos de rutas, lo que me complica un poco son las rutas personalizadas, soy nuevo en laravel y esto me está atrasando un poco. Gracias por tu respuesta!